# Ubuntu 20.04 Bluetooth device only connects after removing it

Tags: drivers, gnome, 20.04, bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker

Most of my Bluetooth devices only connects sucessfully after i remove it. Tried to update packages but no use. It even turn off my bluetooth sometimes...

UPDATE: I use dual boot with windows and i found out that when i connect to the device in windows previously this happens.

Demo:
[image: Demo]

System info:

``````bash
                          ./+o+-       maxjf1@maxjf1-G3-3579
                  yyyyy- -yyyyyy+      OS: Ubuntu 20.04 focal
               ://+//////-yyyyyyo      Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.4.0-47-generic
           .++ .:/++++++/-.+sss/`      Uptime: 7h 7m
         .:++o:  /++++++++/:--:/-      Packages: 1962
        o:+o+:++.`..```.-/oo+++++/     Shell: zsh 5.8
       .:+o:+o/.          `+sssoo+/    Resolution: 1920x1080
  .++/+:+oo+o:`             /sssooo.   DE: GNOME 3.36.4
 /+++//+:`oo+o               /::--:.   WM: Mutter
 \+/+o+++`o++o               ++////.   WM Theme: Adwaita
  .++.o+++oo+:`             /dddhhh.   GTK Theme: WhiteSur-dark [GTK2/3]
       .+.o+oo:.          `oddhhhh+    Icon Theme: WhiteSur-dark
        \+.++o+o``-````.:ohdhhhhh+     Font: Garuda 11
         `:o+++ `ohhhhhhhhyo++os:      Disk: 576G / 1011G (58%)
           .o:`.syhhhhhhh/.oo++o`      CPU: Intel Core i5-8300H @ 8x 2.3GHz [42.0°C]
               /osyyyyyyo++ooo+++/     GPU: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
                   ````` +oo+++o\:     RAM: 5011MiB / 15858MiB
                          `oo++.
``````

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but this keeps happening to me to. This isn't a solution just a mere workaround.

For me, I needed to toggle on the button multiple times to get it working. I posted this on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/gnc8qq/bluetooth_connects_after_many_tries_any_solution/) if you want to see it.

You can install bluetooth quick connect extension from [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1401/bluetooth-quick-connect/). This mostly automatically connects your bluetooth device to your pc. And you can also install blueman by using `sudo apt install blueman` as an alternative if the extension isn't working correctly.

Comment: I already use bluetooth quick connect and it has the same problem. I've tried blueman once, didn't seem to fix it :/

Comment: oh, sorry mate. I don't have any more solutions.

Comment: Please let's find a solution to this. Also, I'm having a problem when I turn on the Bluetooth and connect an audio device, the WiFi goes off. If you know a solution for this, please let me know.

Comment: @DariusP You can post a issue on launchpad, that's our last resort